# core data : phpmyadmin equivalent

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

In my app, I have a pretty huge datamodel and its .sqlite data file. 
I would like to parse my records in the .sqlite file, and I'm wondering if there was a tool, like phpMyAdmin.

It would be an xCode tool, for example, or maybe a custom app downloadable on the web.

Does anyone know that kind of tool ?

Comment: Be careful!  You can poke around in the .sqlite file but [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html) the database format is private, and you shouldn't manipulate the database using the SQLite API.  But where's the fun in that?  (-:

Comment: Hum... thanks for the advice. My use would only be for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of SQLite readers available, but SQLite Manager is popular:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: I tested it, but it doesn't work wery well. For example, it does not support inheritance. let's see other ones...

Comment: Ok, it seems that none of SQLite reader i tested support inheritance. This one is good cause is free.

Answer (score 1):

i like the Core Data Editor, but it is quite expensive (23,99€)
Website:
http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor

Mac App Store:
http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/core-data-editor/id403025957?mt=12

the cool thing is, that core data editor is even able to generate (good and readable) code
[image]